# Missing privilege for "insert [...] on duplicate key update" statement, but enough for "insert" and "update" seperatly

Tags: mariadb, privileges, on-duplicate-key

I tried to reduce the rights a database user has to the minimum needed. Doing so I noticed the following situation:

I have a database `test` and a user `user` with the following privileges:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'user'@'%';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON test.test TO 'user'@'%';
GRANT UPDATE (y) ON test.test TO 'user'@'%';
```

The `test` table (InnoDB) is defined as

```
create table test
(
    x int null,
    y int null
);

create unique index test_x_uindex on test (x);
```

I can run `insert` and `update` queries like

```
INSERT INTO test (x,y) VALUES (1,1), (2,2);
UPDATE test SET y = 3 WHERE x = 1;
```

But running

```
INSERT INTO test (x,y) VALUES (2,4) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE y = VALUES(y);
```

results in

> ERROR 1143 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user 'sap'@'localhost' for column 'x' in table 'test'

The same happens if the statement wouldn't actually update something but just insert a new row.

This seems a little bit odd. I couldn't find a directly related bug report. Just something [older for MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30915) (Is closed but someone said that it is not actually fixed. I did not test it.). In the [documentation of MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) the mention that update privileges are only needed for changed columns. The [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/) does not mention any privilege requirements.

Do I miss something?

This was all tested on MariaDB 10.2.16.

Comment: If it is a MyISAM table not having the `lock` privilege may be the problem.

Comment: Just tried it with MariaDB 10.3.11 and it did not throw an error and the row was updated as expected.

Comment: @Dave I checked and it is an InnoDB table.

Comment: Just tried it again with the table defined as InnoDB and it did not throw an error.

Comment: @Dave Thanks. So it seems to be a bug that is already fixed...

Comment: Possibly though I haven't been able to find any specific references to something related being changed/fixed/updated between the major releases.

Comment: This is rather subtle.  Suggest you file a bug.

Comment: I am also seeing this error with mysql  Ver 8.0.16 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)